# Change between String and Worksheet for the name of a sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm rather new to VBA, so please excuse me if I'm not really used to VBA syntax.

Here is my problem : I have a large number of sheets containing similar data, and I would like to make a procedure to research the data in the cells of every sheet (the cells are always located in the same range of every sheet) and to copy it in my sheet "DETAILS".

I tried to convert the name of every sheet in a string, so I can iterate it (s1, then s2, then...), but when I use **Sheet("s" & 1)**, VBA recognises **"s" & i** as a String and not a sheet.

What can I do to convert **"s" & i** to be recognized as a sheet ?

```
Sub metro()

Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String
Dim s3 As String
Dim s4 As String
Dim s5 As String
Dim s6 As String

Set s1 = "measures"
Set s2 = "data"
Set s3 = "eval1"
Set s4 = "eval2"
Set s5 = "observations"
Set s6 = "improvements"


Dim k As Integer

    For k = 1 To 9
        For i = 1 To 17

        Sheets("s" & i).Cells(56, 2 + k).Value = Worksheets("DETAILS").Cells(18, 14 + k).Value
        i = i + 1
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are your sheets named "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", etc?  Also, your For loops seem backwards if you want to loop through 17 sheets with k being 1 to 9 WITHIN each sheet.  Unless you are doing k as 1 thru all sheets, then k as 2 thru all sheets, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting `"s" & 1` to evaluate to the variable `s1` when it is evaluating to the string `"s1"`.  This is a programming 101 error. variable `x` is not the same as the string or character `"x"`.  You cannot make `"s" & 1` evaluate to `"measures"`.  It will always evaluate to `"s1"` no matter what you do.

You cannot iterate over your sheets by using a numbered naming convention.  You should use an array or collection instead.

```
Dim sheetNames As Variant
sheetNames = Array("measures","data","eval1","eval2","observations","improvements")

Dim k As Integer
For k = 1 To 9
    Dim sheetName As Variant
    For Each sheetName In sheetNames
        Sheets(sheetName).Cells(56, 2 + k).Value = Worksheets("DETAILS").Cells(18, 14 + k).Value
    Next
Next
```

---

Your original question states that you are copying values to `"DETAILS"` when your example is reading from `"DETAILS"`.  Simply reversing the assignment

```
 Worksheets("DETAILS").Cells(18, 14 + k).Value = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(56, 2 + k).Value
```

will cause data in `Worksheets("DETAILS")` to be overwritten every time you iterate the sheets.  The target cell will need to be dependent on `i` from your example.  We can reintroduce `i` by replacing the `For Each` loop with

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
    Worksheets("DETAILS").Cells(18 + i, 14 + k).Values = Sheets(sheetNames(i)).Cells(56, 2 + k).Value 
Next
```

`sheetNames(0)` will evaluate to `"measures"`.  I also made the target cell change with `i`, but you will want to change that to your liking.

---

As already said `Set` is for assigning object references.  It cannot be used for non-object data types like strings, Integers, Arrays.

I also don't know why you are iterating `i` from 1 to 17 when you only list 6 sheet names.

Comment: Aha! You're a bit more insightful. I couldn't figure out why those variables were there; I didn't see what OP was really trying to do. +1

Comment: I'd also add, that per @Christmas007, the loop is probably better reversed (sheets for the outer loop). And *I think* the Details sheet is the target not the source.

Comment: @LimaNightHawk if "DETAILS" is the target then `.Cells(18, 14 + k).Value` will be overwritten as it doesn't iterate with the sheets.  It would need to be dependent on `i` in the original case.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the `Set` before the String assignments; it's causing an error.

I don't think you need to increment `i` in the For loop. That will happen automatically as part of the loop.
Also, i think your assignment is backwards, if I read your post correctly. You want to copy the data from "s1" *to* "DETAILS", right?

One more thing: Each time you loop for a new sheet, your details are going to get overwritten, so you need to change where the data goes for each sheet...perhaps in a new row?

So, this should work, assuming your sheet names are "s1", "s2", etc.

```
Sub metro()

    Dim s1 As String
    Dim s2 As String
    Dim s3 As String
    Dim s4 As String
    Dim s5 As String
    Dim s6 As String

    s1 = "measures"
    s2 = "data"
    s3 = "eval1"
    s4 = "eval2"
    s5 = "observations"
    s6 = "improvements"


    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 17
        For k = 1 To 9
            'adding i to the target row, so that each sheet will not overwrite previous data
            Worksheets("DETAILS").Cells(18 + i, 14 + k).Value = Sheets("s" & i).Cells(56, 2 + k).Value
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```